# Error: The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleIdentifier key

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to submit my iphone app using the altool. However, the following error is being prompted:

```
altool[18508:507] *** Error: (
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectFoundationErrorDomain Code=-27000 \"The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleIdentifier key.\" UserInfo=0x7f {NSLocalizedDescription=The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleIdentifier key., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectFoundationErrorDomain Code=-27001 \"The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key.\" UserInfo=0x7f {NSLocalizedDescription=The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectFoundationErrorDomain Code=-27002 \"The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key.\" UserInfo=0x7f {NSLocalizedDescription=The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectFoundationErrorDomain Code=-27000 \"The package does not contain an Info.plist.\" UserInfo=0x7f{NSLocalizedDescription=The package does not contain an Info.plist., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}"
```

I already verified that such keys (`CFBundleIdentifier`, `CFBundleVersion`, `CFBundleShortVersionString`) are in the Info.plist. In addition, I opened the Payload from the .ipa file (generated with xcodebuild and xcrun - command line) and could confirm that such keys also are in the Info.plist file.

The validation pass when I use the XCode to compile, archive and submit.

Any help?

My Xcode Version: 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
OSX 10.9.5

Comment: Did you event find the answer to this?

Comment: @Jordan Hi. Can you show your build-script for export `*.ipa` file? I have resolved similar issue.

Comment: @Mozilla I resolved it too - I'll add the answer.

Comment: @Mozilla oh you had exactly the same issue. Nice!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue.

```
"Error Domain=ITunesConnectFoundationErrorDomain Code=-27000 \"Could not find a CFBundlePackageType within the Info.plist; or the package is missing an Info.plist.\" UserInfo=0x7fe72051f3a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find a CFBundlePackageType within the Info.plist; or the package is missing an Info.plist., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}"
```

This issue was appeared when I've reworked my script for exporting `*.ipa` with a new `exportOptionsPlist` option. The old script worked OK with `altool`. The new didn't.

Old script:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "MyApp.xcarchive" -exportPath "MyApp.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "appstore-provision"
```

New script:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist "tools/export-options.plist" -archivePath "MyApp.xcarchive" -exportPath "MyApp.ipa"
```

The problem was that the `xcodebuild` now creates `MyApp.ipa/MyApp.ipa` instead of `MyApp.ipa`.

I've changed `-exportPath`:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist "tools/export-options.plist" -archivePath "MyApp.xcarchive" -exportPath "."
```